# PHP form updating multiple mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table I created in PHP with fields that need to be populated.

Here is my PHP form:

```
<td><input type="text" name="reg" value="<? echo $rows['reg']; ?>" readonly/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="driver" value="<? echo $rows['driver']; ?>" readonly/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="departure" value="<? echo $rows['departure']; ?>"/></td>
<th><input type="text" name="destination" /></th>
<th><input type="text" name="sleep" /></th>
<th><input type="text" name="date_loaded" value="<? echo $rows['date_loaded']; ?>"/></th>
<th><input type="text" name="arrival_date" value="<? echo $rows['arrival_date']; ?>"/></th>
<th><input type="text" name="client" value="<? echo $rows['client']; ?>"/></th>
<th><input type="text" name="status" value="<? echo $rows['status']; ?>"/></th>
<th><input type="text" name="notes" value="<? echo $rows['notes']; ?>"/></th>
```

Then I have the following code to update the information to MySQL DB

```
/Post reply drawn 
$client = $_POST['client'];
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$driver = $_POST['driver'];
$departure = $_POST['departure'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$sleep = $_POST['sleep'];
$date_loaded = $_POST['date_loaded'];
$arrival_date = $_POST['arrival_date'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

// Record to MySQL
// database settings

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d") ;
$time = date("H:i:s");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO verification_hx SET
        client = '".$client."',
        reg = '".$reg."',
        driver = '".$driver."',
        departure = '".$departure."',
        destination = '".$destination."',
        sleep = '".$sleep."',
        date_loaded = '".$date_loaded."',
        arrival_date = '".$arrival_date."',
        status = '".$status."',
        notes = '".$notes."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Vehicles has been Updated.  ";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
    echo "Error in Case Management Table";
}

$sql1 = "UPDATE verification SET
        client = '".$client."',
        reg = '".$reg."',
        driver = '".$driver."',
        departure = '".$departure."',
        destination = '".$destination."',
        sleep = '".$sleep."',
        date_loaded = '".$date_loaded."',
        arrival_date = '".$arrival_date."',
        status = '".$status."',
        notes = '".$notes."'
        WHERE reg = .$reg.";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    echo "Error in Bureau Case File Table";
}

$conn->close();
```

Now my problem is it is not updating the form at all, and the new record recorded in the database only has reg and driver details all other details are left blank

Comment: What $_POST array do you get on the server? Do you access the function, where you want to handle the form?

Comment: INSERT INTO verification_hx SET client = '', reg = 'NPN48296', driver = 'FLOYD', departure = '', destination = '', sleep = '', date_loaded = '', arrival_date = '', status = '', notes = ''
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12Error in Bureau Case File Table
I am getting this error

Comment: @Trevor Ackermann: On the last line of you $sql1 the '$reg' is not correct. Some quotes are missing.

Comment: I have added '.$reg.' now the sql error is gone but still not updating the information

Comment: Is the second table a copy of the first one? Are there any rows in it. If yes is there an entry with the `reg` in question?

Comment: The two tables are identical, the reg is the common denominator between both all i need is to update a few rows and create new row in new database based on the table and the different values on reg. reg is also unique thus never the same in the update table

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on PHP side

```
"WHERE reg = .$reg.";
```

It should be

```
"WHERE reg=\'{$reg}\'";
```

As you may find in PHP documentation, try to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) classe instead of date function. You also should look for SQL injection before you publish your project, because users are able to do that inside your code, once you are accepting any string inserted by them with no treating.